# Getting a frame around pandas boxplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a boxplot of a pandas dataframe in python, but I can not get a frame around my plot.

This is the code I am using to plot

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_facecolor('white')
df.boxplot(whis=False, patch_artist=True, ax=ax)

ax.set_frame_on(True)

ax.grid(color='grey', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.6)

ax.set_xticklabels((burstsizes))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,6.6,0.2))
plt.show()
```

This produces following plot: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfD3w.png)

I want to have a frame around the plot but I can not figure out how. I have tried to set a frame with

```
ax.spines['bottom'].setcolor('0.5') # for top left and right too
```

with

```
plt.rcParams["axes.edgecolor"] = "0.15"
plt.rcParams["axes.linewidth"]  = 1.25
```

and with

```
plt.rcParams["axes.grid"] = True
```

all of these solution did not change the plot at all. I believe it might have to do with the way pandas uses matplotlib but I am not sure. Any help would be very much appreciated.
I am using Python 3.5.3.

Comment: Are you importing Seaborn before running this code? Seaborn changes the matplotlib defaults.

Comment: The plot style you have is not the default one. Please provide a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: Importing Seaborn was the Problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: Note that you can also just update to newer versions of seaborn (>=0.8), where such problem would not occur.